# NestJS Get current user in GraphQL resolver authenticated with JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt, graphql, nestjs

I am currently implementing JWT authentication with Passport.js into a NestJS application.

In some of my GraphQL resolvers I need to access the currently authenticated user. I know that passport will attach the authenticated user to the request object (at least I hope that this is correct), but I do not know how to access the request object inside a resolver.

I followed the issue https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1326 and the mentioned link https://github.com/ForetagInc/fullstack-boilerplate/tree/master/apps/api/src/app/auth inside the issue. I saw some code that uses `@Res() res: Request` as a method parameter in the GraphQL resolver methods, but I always get `undefined` for `res`.

These are the current implementations I have:

**GQLAuth**

```
import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ExecutionContextHost } from '@nestjs/core/helpers/execution-context-host';
import { AuthenticationError } from 'apollo-server-core';

@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const { req } = ctx.getContext();
    console.log(req);

    return super.canActivate(new ExecutionContextHost([req]));
  }

  handleRequest(err: any, user: any) {
    if (err || !user) {
      throw err || new AuthenticationError('GqlAuthGuard');
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

**Resolver that needs to access the current user**

```
import { UseGuards, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Resolver, Query, Args, Mutation, Context } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Request } from 'express';

import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './models/user.entity';
import { GqlAuthGuard } from '../auth/guards/gql-auth.guard';

@Resolver(of => User)
export class UserResolver {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  @Query(returns => User)
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
  whoami(@Req() req: Request) {
    console.log(req);
    return this.userService.findByUsername('aw');
  }
}
```

**JWT Strategy**

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtPayload } from './interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Authorization and creating JWT tokens works fine. GraphQL guard also works fine for methods that do not need to access the user. But for methods that need access to the currently authenticated user, I see no way of getting it.

Is there a way to accomplish something like this ?

Comment: Instead of implement your own `canActivate` method in your `GqlAuthGuard` you should create a `getRequest` method and return `GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext().req;`. This is a better approach in my opinion.

Comment: Would you share a link to your GitHub repo? I'm new to Nest.js, I'm also using GraphQL and I'm stuck with the authentication implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Finally found the answer ... https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/48#issuecomment-420693225 pointed me into the right direction of creating a **user decorator**

```
// user.decorator.ts
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data, req) => req.user,
);
```

And then use this in my resolver method:

```
 import { User as CurrentUser } from './user.decorator';

 @Query(returns => User)
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
  whoami(@CurrentUser() user: User) {
    console.log(user);
    return this.userService.findByUsername(user.username);
  }
```

Now everything works as expected. So all credits of this answer goes to https://github.com/cschroeter

Comment: This really needs to be part of the framework and in the default docs, something like this missing makes me think if people are actually using it, lol

Comment: Thank you! Also, as this is a working answer you should accept it even if it's your own.
Thanks again, I searched for a solution for at least an hour before finding this and it worked perfectly.

Comment: In v7 of Nest createParamDecorator has change. Retrieving the user is done through the GraphQL context. See here: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/other-features#custom-decorators

Answer (score 12):

In order to use an AuthGuard with GraphQL, extend the built-in AuthGuard class and override the `getRequest()` method.
Create a file called `gql.guard.ts` (Naming your wish)

```
@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }
}
```

To get the current authenticated user in your graphql resolver, you can define a `@CurrentUser()` decorator (create a file called `user.decorator.graphql.ts`)

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req.user;
  },
);
```

To use above decorator in your resolver, be sure to include it as a parameter of your query or mutation

```
@Query(returns => User)
@UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
whoAmI(@CurrentUser() user: User) {
  return this.usersService.findById(user.id);
}
```

Read More : https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#graphql

Comment: This worked for me on August, 2022

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to validate web token with whatever package you are using, then create  decorator `get-user.decorator.ts`

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';


export const GetUser = createParamDecorator((data, context: ExecutionContext)  => {
 const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext();
return ctx.user
});
```

then in your resolver, you can use this decorator   (@GetUser() user: User)
to access the user

Answer (score 2):

Wish I could take any sort of credit here, I'm simply passing along information from the course, NestJS Zero To Hero (absolutely fantastic btw).

For NestJS 7:

```
// get-user.decorator.ts

import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

import { User } from '../../user/entity/user.entity';

export const GetAuthenticatedUser = createParamDecorator((data, ctx: ExecutionContext): User => {
  const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  return req.user;
});
```

You can implement this however you like. I have an `auth.controller` that looks something like this:

```
// auth.controller.ts

import { GetAuthenticatedUser } from './decarator/get-user.decorator';

...

@Controller('api/v1/auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    //
  }

  ...

  /**
   * Get the currently authenticated user.
   *
   * @param user
   */
   @Post('/user')
   @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
   async getAuthenticatedUser(@GetAuthenticatedUser() user: User) {
     console.log('user', user);
   }
```

Result is something like this:

```
// console.log output:

user User {
  id: 1,
  email: 'email@test.com',
  ...
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for REST services. When using GraphQL you will need to make use of the context associated with GraphQL `GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext()` and not `ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext();
    return ctx.req.user;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data, context: ExecutionContextHost) => {
    return GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext().req.user;
  },
);
```